# Hash values with different data types together?

Tags: python, hash

#### Question:

What is a good way to get a hash from a group of values of different data types (in Python)?

The values need to be hashed in a consistent order. Values that need to be hashed are strings and integers.

#### Example:

```
value1 = 'coconut'
value2 = 1.23

hash = Sha1Hash(value1, value2)
```

Could always concat into a string, but feel like this is less than ideal:

```
hash = Sha1Hash( '%s%s' % (value1, value2))
```

Comment: It depends. Why do you need a hash? What constraints should it satisfy?

Comment: It needs to hash the values in a consistent order. It also needs to hash strings, integers, ans possibly floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a sha1 hash value. Python comes with a sha1 hash function, but it requires a string as input. Your data, `(value1, value2)`, therefore needs to be serialized.

Since your data consists of only strings, ints and floats, you could serialize it and preserve the order of the values with

```
str([value1, value2])
```

---

```
import hashlib

value1 = 'coconut'
value2 = 1.23

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(str([value1, value2]))
print(m.hexdigest())            
# 1381ae81c8a5b660cca5b8d4607aa378320e25e8
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a tuple of the values, and hash that:

```
>>> Sha1Hash((value1, value2))
```

or use the standard [hash](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function:

```
>>> hash((value1, value2))
```